# FuelSDK PHP is returning 302 VersionMismatch and I have no clue why

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, hubexchange

Last week I had a batch job running with FuelSDK-PHP v0.9 against my Client's SalesForce / ExactTarget email marketing account to download subscribers for analysis in another system.

After downloading some 2.1M subscribers (in batches of 2,500 using the moreResults=>1 response node) their API suddenly just returns a 302 Object Moved, and their PHP Classes spit out "Version Mismatch".

Nothing in my code has changed, and yet even when I create a new hub app to get a new client ID and Secret key, it still just issues a 302 to my Subscriber Retrieve query. It's also way, way below the 50,000 API calls per day courtesy limit. In fact, I am now getting this same 302 redirect response on Monday morning the first time I run the script after the weekend.

If anyone is interested I've posted my entire code [here](https://gist.github.com/phpguru/8ae0ea2e299d984c56e8) - It's far from being complicated; based on their examples. I also posted about it in the [SalesForce Developer Forums](https://gist.github.com/phpguru/8ae0ea2e299d984c56e8).

Answer (score 0):

This was actually due to a problem with the Exact Target API endpoint, and after using Twitter and Email, I was able to get to the right guys at SalesForce, who later asked me to "try your query again" at which time it started working again, with no changes to my code.